# assignment in 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: python

I am working with Python 3.5.

This is my code:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b=a[:][:]
a[0][0]=7
print(a) # [[7, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(b) # [[7, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I need `b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. How do you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use deepcopy:

```
>>> import copy
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> a[0][0]=7
>>> print(a)
[[7, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> print(b)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy
b = deepcopy(a)
```

or simply:

```
b = [row[:] for row in a]
```